# Remove duplicate arrays in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove duplicate arrays in a multidimensional array?

This is my original array with `[1]` and `[2]` being identical.

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Walter
            [1] => White
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Marie
            [1] => Schrader
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Marie
            [1] => Schrader
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hank
            [1] => Schrader
        )

)
```

What I like to achieve:

```
$array_without_duplicates = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Walter
            [1] => White
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Marie
            [1] => Schrader
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hank
            [1] => Schrader
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$results = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  $results[implode($v)] = $v;
}

$results = array_values($results);
print_r($results);
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/jMzSA8)

If you also want to consider keys when checking for equality, replace `implode($v)` with `serialize($v)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    $i++;
    $j=0;
    foreach($arr as $key2=>$val2){
        $j++;
        if($j<=$i){continue;}
        if($val===$val2){
            unset($arr[$key2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug output:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Walter [1] => White ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Marie [1] => Schrader ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Hank [1] => Schrader ) )

Comment: Plus: Notice: Undefined offset: 2

Answer (score -2):

You can get rid of duplicates using array_unique with SORT_REGULAR

```
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: works only on unidimensional array

Comment: This answer is provably correct and @vishwa's comment is provably incorrect. https://3v4l.org/86Dqa  This answer's advice is found on the canonical dupe target page.