# change original array values inside foreach php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, array-unset

I want to update an array inside foreach I tried this two code :

code 1 :

```
 foreach ($listOrders as $k => $order) {

    foreach ($listOrders as $key => $o) 
    {
      if ($o["id_order"] == $order["id_order"])
      {
         unset($listOrders[$key]);
      }
    }
```

in this codeunset is not working

code 2 :

```
     foreach ($listOrders as $k => &$order) {

     foreach ($listOrders as $key => $o) 
     {
        if ($o["id_order"] == $order["id_order"])
        {
           unset($listOrders[$key]);
        }
     }
```

If I use & with $order $listOrders will not returned all data that I want.

Comment: sorry but `$listOrders == $listOrders` you code always return empty array, you can update code, or this is  a error,

Comment: Why are you iterating through the list twice?

Comment: @aynber the OP needs to loop twice because in the column (or field) "o" it can have the value of the column (or field) "order" maybe... and those will be the same in different rows?

Comment: I want to delete other rows from the list with same id_order

Comment: Take a look at `array_map` http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-map.php there is also `array_filter`.  Map returns an array of the same size with the value "swapped" (as a new array) with the outcome of the function, filter, returns an array filtered by the outcome of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your error should be here

```
  foreach ($listOrders as $k => &$order) { 
                                ^
```

Remove **&**

Also you are iterating through your $listOrders twice with your code, won't your array list always be empty after the iteration is finished?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to get a list of the orders in the list, you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to index the list by `id_order`.  As you can only ever have 1 entry in an array with a particular key, this will end up with the last entry with a particular order id in the array...

```
$uniqueList = array_column(listOrders, null, "id_order");
```

If you just need the list without the index, you can use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-index the list.

```
$uniqueList = array_values(array_column(listOrders, null, "id_order"));
```

Comment: Canonical, if you feel your advice is most appropriate: [Filter/Remove rows where column value is found more than once in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603614/2943403)