# Counting a unique value from an Array set

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-unique

I have an array that repeats the same values twice. I am unable to count the total of the unique values. I mean the phone number is unique and when the same phone number appears twice it should be counted as one.

I have tried by using the method array_unique. To count the total number of the unique values. It however returns the total number of the array instead. Kindly help me fix this.

```
<div class="c100 p100 big dark green">
    <?php
    $url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // path to your JSON file
    //$url = 'data.json'; // path to your JSON file
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
    $characters = json_decode($data);
    $array = array_values(array_unique($characters, SORT_REGULAR));
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $character) {
        $i++;
        ?>
    <?php }
    ?>
    <span>
    <?php
    echo $i;
    ?>
    </span>
    <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON

```
[{"name":"xxxxxxxx","phoneNumber":"222223wssd","amount":50.00,"won":false,"date":"2019-05-01T02:35:38"},
{"name":"xxxxxxxx","phoneNumber":"222223wssd","amount":60.05,"won":false,"date":"2019-05-01T09:01:04"}]
```

The expected value should count the unique values and not all the values in the array.

Comment: what do you mean unique? unique in the object? inside the array? can you please try to explain better?

Comment: Are the two items in your json one or two unique items? And why is it then one or two items?

Comment: I meant the phone number is unique and when it appears twice it should be counted as one.

Comment: Related: [How to remove duplicate values from a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603614/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_column to only get the unique phone number items.
This code makes the array associative on phone number which means it deletes duplicates.

Then I use count() to count the number of items instead of looping the array.

```
$json = '[{"name":"xxxxxxxx","phoneNumber":"222223wssd","amount":50.00,"won":false,"date":"2019-05-01T02:35:38"},
{"name":"xxxxxxxx","phoneNumber":"222223wssd","amount":60.05,"won":false,"date":"2019-05-01T09:01:04"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$unique = array_column($arr, null, 'phoneNumber');

echo count($unique) . "\n";

var_dump($unique);
```

Output:

```
1 //count()
array(1) { // var_dump()
  ["222223wssd"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "xxxxxxxx"
    ["phoneNumber"]=>
    string(10) "222223wssd"
    ["amount"]=>
    float(60.05)
    ["won"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-05-01T09:01:04"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/A4p6d