# Compare two multidimensional array and get data by value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional array

```
// Array 1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/heythere.jpg
            [source] => database
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/test.jpg
            [source] => database
        )

);

// Array 2
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/heythere.jpg
            [source] => directory
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/demo.jpg
            [source] => directory
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/image.jpg
            [source] => directory
        )

);
```

There is similar data in both the arrays like;
/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/heythere.jpg

I want to merge these two arrays in one but only unique elements by value also I need to get the element of Array1 if the values are same

So after merging two array I want this result:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/demo.jpg
            [source] => directory
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/image.jpg
            [source] => directory
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/heythere.jpg
            [source] => database
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [src] => /wp-content/uploads/2019/09/test.jpg
            [source] => database
        )


);
```

It will skip "directory" similar element.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is an unattempted, two-part question: 1. merge the two arrays, then 2. [filter duplicate src values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603614/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$array1 = [
    [
        'src' => '/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/heythere.jpg',
        'source' => 'database'
    ],
    [
        'src' => '/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/test.jpg',
        'source' => 'database'
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    [
        'src' => '/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/heythere.jpg',
        'source' => 'directory'
    ],
    [
        'src' => '/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/demo.jpg',
        'source' => 'directory'
    ],
    [
        'src' => '/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/image.jpg',
        'source' => 'directory'
    ]
];

$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$uniqueIndexes = array_unique(array_column($result, 'src'));

// remove non unique indexes
foreach ($result as $i => $_) {
    if (!isset($uniqueIndexes[$i])) {
        unset($result[$i]);
    }
}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df1e8875dafebe22aef45f4e0332758a40edf240)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge` with `array_column` and `array_values`

```
$u = array_values(array_column(array_merge($a1,$a2), null, 'src'));
```

Live example :- https://3v4l.org/gkY3a