# Merge two 2d arrays and remove duplicate rows

Tags: php, merge, closures, array-merge

I searched a lot of SOF threads and no one seems to stick to my problem. What's kind of wired because this should be a well discussed question :)

Maybe I'm seeking for the wrong thing...

**Scenario:**

I have 2 arrays

```
$a = [ 
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'bruce'],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'wayne']
];
// 2 elements
```

and

```
$b = [
    ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'chuck'],
    ['id' => 8, 'name' => 'norris'],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'wayne'] //also exists in array $a
];
// 3 elements
```

My goal is

```
$c = [
    ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'chuck'],
    ['id' => 8, 'name' => 'norris'],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'wayne'],
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'bruce']
];
// 4 elements (no duplicates)
```

I really don't care about the order inside the array(s) but I want to merge both into one, without having duplicates.

I tried **array_merge** and **array_merge_recursive**. No one works. Probably because the functions doesn't know the identifier which identifies each entry. Is there an easy solution or do I really have to create an own method/function for this?

Maybe there is a closure that I could use?

Comment: Would you not consider a closure, writing your own function?

Comment: Relevant: [Filter/Remove rows where column value is found more than once in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603614/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with very simple inbuilt function of PHP

```
$c = array_unique(array_merge($a,$b), SORT_REGULAR);
print_r( $c )
```

The output of the print_r is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => bruce
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => wayne
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => chuck
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => norris
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = array_merge($b, $a);
foreach ($temp as $v) {
    $c[$v['id']] = $v;
}
```

If it finds the same id, the element will be overwritten in $c

Comment: this is quite what I mean with `do i really have to create an own method/function`, but still +1 for short code :)

Comment: If you want just to merge the array, you can give the $a and $b arrays string indexes and use array_merge

`    $a = [`
`        "i5"=>['id' => 5, 'name' => 'bruce'],`
`        "i7"=>['id' => 7, 'name' => 'wayne']`
`    ];`

$b = [
    "i6"=>['id' => 6, 'name' => 'chuck'],
    "i8"=>['id' => 8, 'name' => 'norris'],
    "i7"=>['id' => 7, 'name' => 'wayne']
];

$c=array_merge($a, $b);
`

Comment: the data i get is defined as it is. So I get numbers not strings :) But thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: This is great, if the ids and the names are always paired the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how performant this is, but just using phps array-manipulation functions I get:

```
>>> array_values(array_merge(array_combine(array_column($a, 'name'), $a), array_combine(array_column($b, 'name'), $b)));
=> [
     [
       "id" => 5,
       "name" => "bruce",
     ],
     [
       "id" => 7,
       "name" => "wayne",
     ],
     [
       "id" => 6,
       "name" => "chuck",
     ],
     [
       "id" => 8,
       "name" => "norris",
     ],
   ]
```

Comment: but this turns out as a assoc array. Ok, you have choosen name instead of id, Does this works with integer id's as well?

Comment: Edited in an `array_values` call :)

Comment: just like i commented to an other post, Guess there are many ways leading to Rom :D Some are longer and some are shorter :) for documetation reasons, +1 for this answere

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach at hashing each array with serialize after a key sort:

```
<?php

$a = [ 
    ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'bruce'],
    ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'wayne']
];

$b = [
    ['id' => 6, 'name' => 'chuck'],
    ['name' => 'wayne', 'id' => 7],
    ['id' => 8, 'name' => 'norris']
];
$merged = array_merge($a, $b);

foreach($merged as $k => $v) {
    ksort($v);
    $hashes[$k] = serialize($v);
}
$hashes = array_unique($hashes);
var_export(array_intersect_key($merged, $hashes));
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 5,
      'name' => 'bruce',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 7,
      'name' => 'wayne',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => 6,
      'name' => 'chuck',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8,
      'name' => 'norris',
    ),
  )
```

Comment: a bit longer source and I guess since I could not find a solution before this answere is good for documenation reasons :) Guess there are many ways leading to Rom :D Some are longer and some are shorter :)

Comment: This will possibly break for deeper similar arrays with elements in different orders.  The ksort fixes that for flat arrays (would require recursively ksorting otherwise).  array_unique / SORT_REGULAR will break if arrays are similar but in different orders, it will fail to sort, and then won't discard similar items.  Probably not an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

If you index them on unique `id` then just add them.  The result will be indexed on `id` which is convenient:

```
$result = array_column($a, null, 'id') + array_column($b, null, 'id');
```

Comment: works as well, even if its a bit more code than accepted answere. And unique array also reindexes as well if i got this right. so wrapping yours with array_values would do the same than. :D

Comment: Yes, but if something is unique like `id` then personally prefer to have it indexed on that.