# how eliminate duplicates by two fields from a multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

```
    Array
    (
        [piata-fortei-munca] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:07
                        [user] => 61006cd2ac1728c3c08c2e8d9d714a81
                        [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:07
                        [user] => 61006cd2ac1728c3c08c2e8d9d714a81
                        [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:09
                        [user] => a8b6c2879aa0f38da1fd49a4e86e1525
                        [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:09
                        [user] => a8b6c2879aa0f38da1fd49a4e86e1525
                        [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:18
                        [user] => 42d80d8dc9a9547223e2bfea172738cf
                        [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
                    )
[blockchain-bitcoin] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-10-19 08:10:58
                    [user] => 4b01473f1d3f1846b1e83b33e1af0b11
                    [slug] => blockchain-bitcoin
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2019-10-19 08:10:58
                    [user] => 4b01473f1d3f1846b1e83b33e1af0b11
                    [slug] => blockchain-bitcoin
                )

        )
)
```

i have an array structure like this
i want to remove duplicates

for example, for key [piata-fortei-munca]
multiple arrays have same user and slug
[user] => 61006cd2ac1728c3c08c2e8d9d714a81
[slug] => piata-fortei-munca

if same  user and slug exist then remove the multiple entries from array
if anybody knows the logic ,please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @LetsSeo not getting

Comment: I find dissonance between the question requirements and the accepted answer.  If the accepted answer is correct, then the question is wrong and this page can be closed with https://stackoverflow.com/q/45603614/2943403.  If the question requirements are correct, then Nigel's answer is correct and there is surely another duplicate that can be used to close this page with.  The asker seems to ask for uniqueness based on two columns, but the [mcve] is low-quality because the `date` values do not differ -- this means that whole rows can be used to determine uniqueness (by happenstance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_walk` with `array_column` and `array_values`

```
array_walk($a, function(&$v ,$k){
    $v  = array_values(array_column($v, null, 'user'));
});
print_r($a);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/k3d4T

Comment: This doesn't work with the slug as well, as they ask *if same user and slug exist*, it just happens that they have the same slug in the example code which is why this works.

Comment: Not sure, but I assumed they meant a combination of the two, but that is up to OP.

Comment: @NigelRen let's wait for OP response, i will monitor this one.

Answer (score 0):

As it is 2 of the 3 values you want to get as the unique identity, you can combine these two values to create a composite key for a temporary array.  Then once you have created this intermediate array, use `array_values()` to remove the composite key...

```
$output = [];
foreach ( $data['piata-fortei-munca'] as $entry )   {
    $output[$entry['user']."#".$entry['slug']] = $entry;
}

print_r(array_values($output));
```

with your test data gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:07
            [user] => 61006cd2ac1728c3c08c2e8d9d714a81
            [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:09
            [user] => a8b6c2879aa0f38da1fd49a4e86e1525
            [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-10-19 09:10:18
            [user] => 42d80d8dc9a9547223e2bfea172738cf
            [slug] => piata-fortei-munca
        )

)
```