# Filter array rows where two column values have been encountered before (in either order)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, filtering

I Have some problem with some value on array at php, here is the array

```
array:4 [ 
  0 => array:7 [
    "id" => 76
    "id_sender" => 1
    "id_receiver" => 2
    "message" => "2 Miliar"
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:17.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:17.000000Z"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [
    "id" => 75
    "id_sender" => 1
    "id_receiver" => 3
    "message" => "1 Miliar"
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:10.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:10.000000Z"
  ]
  2 => array:7 [
    "id" => 74
    "id_sender" => 3
    "id_receiver" => 1
    "message" => "Property ini berapa harganya?"
    "is_read" => 1
    "created_at" => "2022-11-28T13:52:57.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-11-28T13:55:37.000000Z"
  ]
  3 => array:7 [
    "id" => 73
    "id_sender" => 2
    "id_receiver" => 1
    "message" => "Untuk yang ini berapa harganya?"
    "is_read" => 1
    "created_at" => "2022-11-28T13:07:34.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-11-28T13:55:33.000000Z"
  ]
]
```

That's my array, I want to skip the the value on index 2 and 3 because I've already the value

for example

```
id_sender = 1 && id_receiver = 3,
```

because on index 2 i already have value, even it is reverse

```
id_sender = 3 && id_receiver = 1,
```

that's put on check of id_receiver of index 2, and another conditions and so one,

the result i want are like this

```
array:2 [ 
  0 => array:7 [
    "id" => 76
    "id_sender" => 1
    "id_receiver" => 2
    "message" => "2 Miliar"
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:17.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:17.000000Z"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [
    "id" => 75
    "id_sender" => 1
    "id_receiver" => 3
    "message" => "1 Miliar"
    "is_read" => 0
    "created_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:10.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2022-11-28T13:57:10.000000Z"
  ]
]
```

How can I solve that in php?

** EDIT **

I tried using array_filter, but it didn't change anything:

```
$member1 = 1;
$member2 = 3;

array_filter($items_message, function($v, $k) use ($member1, $member2) {
    return (($k == 'id_sender' && $v == $member1) && ($k == 'id_receiver' && $v == $member2 )) || (($k == 'id_sender' && $v == $member2) && ($k == 'id_receiver' && $v == $member1 ));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "skip"? Did you try to use `array_filter` for that?

Comment: i mean i would like to skip the value if id_sender & id_receiver have some value (1, 3) or reversed (3, 1) i have already use array_filter, but still confused how to use the built in featyre of array filter if there is more than 2 conditions, wait i edit and give some example of the array_filter that i used

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Your condition is always `false`

Comment: glad to know for the summary of conditions, but, the issue is not at the array_filter, it is the above edited function, what i mean  is a logical answer about the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find a way to know what you've seen so far while looping through your array.

A solid solution would be to use a pairing function, to create some unique number out of the 2 numbers you have. Pairing functions do not give the same result if the numbers are inverted, so we'll need to make sure we feed both numbers in the same order, to do that we'll use the smallest number of the two first. You'd then be able to easily determine if you already encountered the pair.

I am sorry my PHP is very rusty, so I'll use something similar but the code won't work.

```
function almostCantorPair(a, b){
  if($a > $b){
    $big = $a;
    $small = $b;
  } else {
    $small = $a;
    $big = $b;
  }
  return (($small + $big) / 2) * ($small + $big + 1) + $big
}
```

You would then loop through your array, take the return of this "almost" cantor pair (almost because we switch the numbers as explained above). You'd check if you have it in an array, if not you push the object to your result array and add that pair to your "known" array. If you find a pair, then you simply ignore the object.

```
$visitedPairs = new array();
$result = new Array();
foreach ($array as $elem) {

  $pair = almostCantorPair($elem['id_sender'], $elem['id_receiver']);
  if(!in_array($pair,$visitedPairs)){
    array_push($result,$elem);
    array_push($visitedPairs,$pair);
  } 
}
```

About pairing function, Wikipedia sums it up very well:

> In mathematics, a pairing function is a process to uniquely encode two natural numbers into a single natural number.

Comment: Don't you mean `if(!in_array(pair,$visitedPairs))` (not)?

Comment: Cleaned up the 'rust'

Comment: waw, i need to read the pairing function, more of my code problem are solvedby using string of any value id that shows up, but i hink your solutions might be better. But, i need to learn the cantor pair first before take it out

Comment: @Appem do know that pairing functions might have ways to revert to the 2 initial IDs, that also may be useful some times. The CantorPair is indeed reversible.

Answer (score 1):

While iterating, isolate the sender and receiver ids as a temporary array, sort the two elements, then implode them as a string -- this will give you a reliable value to use as the key in result array.  With these new associative first-level keys in your result array, you can use the null coalescing assignment operator to only store the first occurring row for each respective id set.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/saQYk))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            $array,
            function($result, $row) {
                $ids = [$row['id_sender'], $row['id_receiver']];
                sort($ids);
                $result[implode(',', $ids)] ??= $row;
                return $result;
            }
        )
    )
);
```

If you prefer a classic loop to iterate, then this is equivalent to the above snippet ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ss80H))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $ids = [$row['id_sender'], $row['id_receiver']];
    sort($ids);
    $result[implode(',', $ids)] ??= $row;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Relevant reading: [Filter/Remove rows where column value is found more than once in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604306/2943403)